# How to send a javascript array to the Servlet

Tags: javascript, arrays, servlets

I have an application where i am getting some values in the console in the form of a javascript array.now i want to send the values to the servlet.My javascript array look like this ..

```
0.Java
1.Perl
2.C#
```

This values i am getting in the console.i have to send those values to the Servlet.But i can not do that.I am able to send multiple values to the Servlet,but dont know how to send array of javascript.The way i send multiple values to the Servlet is

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "AccountServlet",
        type: "post",

        dataType: "json",
        data: { subject1:java,subject2:perl..etc},
        error:function(){
            //alert("error occured!!!");
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data.fullName + "\n" + data.mobileNo);
        }
     });
```

and in the Servlet i catch them

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String sub1=request.getParameter("subject1");
            String sub2=request.getParameter("subject2);
    ;
```

Like this but can anyone help me how to store array of javascript here.
    }

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle this, but the easiest would be to pass the array as one parameter in your javascript code and then retrieve it as a string in your Java code.  use a JSON library like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Simple JSON](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) to parse the array from the string into a native Java array.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] arr = gson.fromJson(request.getParamenter("subjects"), String[].class); 
 // ... do more here
}
```